# What is the Necessary math to understand books?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, books, mathematical-programming, mathematical-foundations

I have many problems understanding algorithms described in the books.

Well, I'm talking about the mathematical description of a problem.

For example: I don't understand how the math of Unscented Kalman Filter works. 
I have spent many days studying good books but for me just code make sense.

I have the basic math from the college but something is missing and I don't know what is.
I need understand math because I should translate math to code.

Can you help me saying what is missing?

Thank you, and sorry for any english mistakes.

Comment: If books are too hard to understand, try to write it on google => (https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-Kalman-filter)

Comment: What is your question? How to understand Kalman filters? How to understand all algorithms (surely too broad)? What is missing from your maths education (how would we know)?

Comment: Hello David, all 3 questions are my questions. But the second( math algorithms) and the last (requisits to understand math algorithms that I don't have) are more relevant